# How to get dwarves to find missing dwarves

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I had two of my mining dwarves mine a few levels down, and they died. I can see them by going down and their corpses and picks are lying there, making miasma. There are ramps going down to where they are, but none of my dwarves are hauling them up. I need the picks badly.

Comment: Could you take screenshots of both levels the ramps are on?

Comment: Also, how did the dwarves die?

Comment: Are their picks marked as "forbidden" or "dump"? It's a long time ago I last played DF, but IIRC, when dwarves die in combat, their corpses and equipment get auto-forbidden to prevent civilians from trying to pick them up before the threat is eliminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. The dwarves and their picks were marked as forbid, for some reason, so I just went to them with k and reclaimed them.

Comment: There's an option, on by default, to auto-forbid items of dead dorfs, iirc, it's at [o]-[F]-something. Same for fired bolts. I always switch them off.